# How to post to a users wall as the App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

I have build a Facebook-app that needs to post to the users wall in certain situations. I've come a long way in doing this: it works perfectly, even when the user is not logged in. However, I need to post to the user's wall on behalf of the app, not the user himself. The reason is that posting as the user will not trigger a notification.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Although you cannot just post to a wall because you want to, if the user does something, just like getting a high score or a rank, you can post in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible; apps cannot post to the profiles of users - if you want someone to come back to your app, you could use a Request which will increment the counter on the user's bookmark for your app, but it's not possible to post to a user's profile 'from' a page or application

Comment: Thanks Igy. So this means I can not send a notification to a user?